# ¿Cómo puedo transformar datos en SQL y manipularlos después?

Tags: sql, oracle

el problema es el siguiente: tengo dos tablas, una con votantes y otra con las localidades a las que pertenecen. Cada votante tiene un nivel de estudios descrito textualmente, y el ejercicio me pide que determine el nivel medio de estudios por localidad.

Se me ha ocurrido transformar los datos a números usando una sentencia case, pero no sé cómo agruparlos después por localidad, así que me preguntaba si podríais echarme una mano en ese aspecto. He intentado poner un AVG delante del case y agruparlo por L.nombre, pero no sirve de nada.

El código hasta el que he podido llegar es el siguiente:

```
  SELECT L.NOMBRE,  CASE
WHEN ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES='Ninguno' THEN 0
WHEN ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES='Basicos' THEN 1
WHEN ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES='Superiores' THEN 2
WHEN ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES='Doctorado' THEN 3
END AS "NIVEL DE ESTUDIOS"
FROM VOTANTES V, LOCALIDADES L
WHERE V.LOCALIDAD=L.IDLOCALIDAD
```

Comment: La pregunta no es del todo clara, pero creo que lo que tendrías que hacer es **contar** agrupando por localidades y por nivel de estudio y luego sacar un promedio. Quizá si pones un pequeño dataset y un ejemplo de los resultados que esperas obtener podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Estas preguntas siempre deben ir con una descripción de las tablas y algún dato de prueba para que otros puedan probar sus respuestas y ayudarte más rápido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: RECREACIÓN DE TABLA: TB_VOTANTES]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola Mateo, espero no haber entendido mal la pregunta. Asumiendo que tiene tablas similares a estas, donde la primera es la tabla de votantes y la segunda la de localidades, la solución sería:

```
SELECT L.DESCRIPCION,
   V.NIVEL_ESTUDIOS,
   COUNT(*) AS CANTIDAD_VOTANTES
FROM TB_LOCALIDAD AS L
INNER JOIN TB_VOTANTES AS V
ON L.ID_LOCAL = V.ID_LOCAL
WHERE V.ID_LOCAL = 2 -- ID DE LA LOCALIDAD QUE BUSCAS
GROUP BY V.NIVEL_ESTUDIOS;
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultados enter tb_votantes y tb_localidad]

El "***INNER JOIN***" une las tablas para posteriormente hacer un filtro por localidad y, finalmente, lo agrupamos por el nivel de estudios.

Answer (score 2):

Si no he entendido mal la pregunta, con esto solucionará tu problema...
He intentado usar parte de lo que te indica A. Cedano

Al no tener la tabla y demás, no he podido probarlo... Espero que te sea de utilidad.

```
SELECT L.NOMBRE AS LOCALIDAD,
(SELECT AVG(COUNT(ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES)) FROM VOTANTES V WHERE V.LOCALIDAD = L.IDLOCALIDAD GROUP BY ESTUDIOSSUPERIORES, LOCALIDAD) AS "NIVEL DE ESTUDIOS"
FROM LOCALIDADES L
```

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Tu idea esta bien, sólo es agrupar *por localidad*:

```
SELECT l.idlocalidad
     ,  avg ( CASE estudiossuperiores
               WHEN 'Ninguno' THEN 0
               WHEN 'Basicos' THEN 1
               WHEN 'Superiores' THEN 2
               WHEN 'Doctorado' THEN 3
             END
           ) as "NIVEL DE ESTUDIOS"
  FROM votantes v
    INNER JOIN localidades l
      ON l.idlocalidad = v.localidad
  GROUP BY l.idlocalidad
```